# getElementsByTagName doesn't work with some tags

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a code in vba to parse data from some websites using xmlhttp request but I noticed that `getElementsByTagName` method works just for some specific tags.

I prepared the following simple code to test it. The code works with some specific tags like `span`, `div`, `ls`, `a` & `b` but not for others! (you can change the TestTag variable and test it)

I don't know the reason. I searched for the answer and faced with some content about namespace, I read about it but I couldn't find any relation between my problem and this. Please help me to understand the problem.

```
Sub TEST()
    
    'Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object
    Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    'Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLDiv As Object
    Dim TestTag As String
    
    TestTag = "div"
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = "<BODY><" & TestTag & _
    "><FIRSTTAG><SPAN class=firstclass>FirstContent<SECTAG>-SecContent</SECTAG></SPAN></FIRSTTAG> </" & _
    TestTag & "></BODY>"
    
    Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName(TestTag).Item(0)
    MsgBox HTMLDiv.innerText

End Sub
```

**Update:** I changed the code to late binding to be easily used and tested without setting reference objects.

Comment: I don't think `getElementsByTagName` works with custom tag names.  Would help to show some actual example of tag names you weren't able to access using that method.

Comment: Your example works for me using Excel 2019 (with mshtml.dll  file version 11.0.22000.556) and I used `banana` as my TestTag. Do you have a specific failing value in mind?  What you have described is certainly familiar from lessons in the past but there have been some crazy undocumented things going on with mshtml.dll over last year or so.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you for your response."Banana" doesn't work for me! I'm using Excel 2010 and mshtml.dll ver. 11.0.9600.17842. I'm trying some tags like "lx", "pos","firsttag" and ... but the code doesn't return any result for them.

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for editing tags. I thought this method is used in .net and also vb.net as well as vba, isn't it?
and about working `getElementsByTagName` working with specific tags, I don't think so.
Actually I was using my code without any problem when I was using IE instead of xmlhttp request. In that code I had assigned the html to a variable declared as Object not htmldoc and when I used `getElementsByTagName` for that variable I could get the results I wanted.

Comment: After testing a bit more: using a tagname "banana" the method does retrieve a nodelist, but the one member of that list has empty values for (eg) innerText.  Although the elements are collected they cannot be used for anything...  mshtml version 7.0.3300

Comment: I can still run and get the same output as if using `div`. The fails are with absolutely expected cases such as starting tag name with a number or special character. Depending what you want to do with the input files perhaps you could wangle your way through using XML library to parse for custom tags. Additionally, you could <sharp intake of breath> use regex to swop out known tags with a tag which will parse and add a custom attribute e.g. class. Or, with XML set-up a transform process.